# getting anti virus status with .net 3.5 not from WMI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, wmi, antivirus

the problem is that i can't rely on the status code from SecurityCenter (WMI) because each provider has a different status code for each product state (Active and updated, Deactivated and updated, Active and not updated, Deactivated and 
not updated) and any method to manipulate it wasn't 100% bullet proof.

any idea how to get the status in another way

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, the question it seems you really can get antivirus status, but your problem is that you don't know how to much the statuses between all possible providers, and this is other problem

Comment: I need to check between 4 product states: Active and updated, Deactivated and updated, Active and not updated, Deactivated and not updated. and each provider has different code for each state

Comment: You have to cover all possible providers in the market ?, and have you checked this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-the-status-of-4b748f25

Comment: Yes i tried it, but i want something more robust